# How many of the Ainur did not descend into Eä

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion, valar

We know that many Ainur entered Eä at the beginning of time, the most powerful forming the Valar and the lesser the Maiar, but how many remained behind with Eru? Does Tolkien ever discuss this in any of his letters?

Comment: We don't even know how many Maiar entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### We don't know

Tolkien wrote extremely little about the Timeless Halls in general, and most of what he did write only concerns the spirits who would go on to have interactions with Elves and Men.

We know nothing at all about the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

No, he did not write anything about them. The no of the Ainur who entered Arda is only known but not of ones left behind nor the total no of Ainur in the whole universe.

Comment: Even the number who entered Arda is unknown.  We know all of the Valar, but we have no idea how many Maiar there are and only a small number are identified.